# Hide haml if anything but a desktop

Tags: javascript, haml

I have a js class that is able to define what kind of device I'm on. The class will return a bool if I ask for `desktop` or `phone`. The problem is I want my html/haml to be dynamic based on what the javascript bool is. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this. You can have **both** the `desktop` and `phone` html in your file and selectively show the appropriate HTML.

```
<body>
<div id="desktop_content">
...
</div>
<div id="mobile_content">
...
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (desktop) {
  document.getElementById('desktop_content').display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('mobile_content').display = 'none';
} else {
  document.getElementById('mobile_content').display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('desktop_content').display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could pull the content in using an AJAX request (using jQuery):

```
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (desktop) {
  $('#content').load('desktop_content.html');
} else {
  $('#content').load('mobile_content.html');
}
</script>
```